# how can I strip everything after the third "\"?

Tags: excel, formula

I have this:

```
Y:\Data\FS02-V\Aetna\DataProcessing\ProcessDocumentation\Control-M
```

I want the cell to read:

```
FS02-V\Aetna
```

It will always be the information between the second and fourth slash.  How can I do this with a formula in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mid,Find and substitute:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",2))+1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",4))-FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",2))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I made a few modifications to this as my original question was unclear but this worked like a charm!! Thanks so much.